# How to reuse variables in a d3.js selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

While trying to clean up my d3.js code i always hit walls because i don't know how to reuse my variables.

Is there a way to get variables and reuse them as in the commented lines?

```
var runStartAnimation = function(){
  d3.selectAll(".allArcs").transition().duration(1500).delay(1000)
  // obviously totaly bad syntax. This is just for clarification.
  // var startAngle = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("start"));
  // var endAngle = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("end"));

  .tween("d", tweenMoveArc(
    // startAngle,startAngle,startAngle,endAngle
    parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("start")),
    parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("start")),
    parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("start")),
    parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("end"))
  ));

}
```

I know this might not be the most usefull example but I hope you understand my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax would look like this:

```
var runStartAnimation = function(){
   var startAngle = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("start")),
       endAngle = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("end"));

   d3.selectAll(".allArcs").transition().duration(1500).delay(1000)
      .tween("d", tweenMoveArc(
          startAngle,startAngle,startAngle,endAngle
      ));

}
```

When you use `.tween`, you're chaining the `tween` method onto the value returned by `d3.selectAll(".allArcs").transition().duration(1500).delay(1000)`, so you can't put the variable definition between those two lines.

The important thing to keep in mind is what the scope of these variables is going to be. Since they are in the scope of `runStartAnimation`, they'll have the data of whatever element that function is being called on, not the data in each of the elements in your `.allArcs` selection. If you want the data to be specific to each of those elements, you would need to define a function scoped to the element that you want, inside which you could define variables and use them, like so:

```
 d3.selectAll(".allArcs").transition().duration(1500).delay(1000)
      .tween("d", function(d){
          //We're now in a function scoped to each element in our selection
          var startAngle = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("start")),
              endAngle = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("end"));

          return tweenMoveArc(startAngle,startAngle,startAngle,endAngle);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can save them just like any other variables:

```
.tween("d", function() {
  var sel = d3.select(this),
      start = parseFloat(sel.attr("start")),
      end = parseFloat(sel.attr("end"));
  return tweenMoveArc(start, start, start, end);
));
```

Comment: TweenMoveArc is a function which accepts 4 parameters. In your example i don't understand what is going on at all but I feel like it's not going to satisfy tweenMoveArc().

can you explain a little bit please?